# Ways to obtain new portrait photography clients?

Tags: portrait, selling

I'd like to increase my portrait business. I've had good experiences with family, pet portraits and High School seniors.

My local newspaper is quite expensive. I've had okay luck with Craigslist, although Craiglist shoppers are far from my ideal client that is willing to pay for quality images, fast turn around and a great experience.

I have a flyer on my community message board, but not enough traffic walks by it. I was thinking about posting at my local churches. I get a few of referrals from friends and family of clients.

What are good ways to reach my local base and increase sales?

Comment: Print thousands of adds on paper, get on a bike and put them in the mail of the people living in your neighborhood.

Comment: Word of mouth from satisfied customers is always the best form of advertisement.

Answer (score 1):

In the long run, in prder to create a reputation, You can simply walk around and ask permission to random people in the street to take a photograph. Something like humans of new york.

Find your excuses, than tell, if they want you can send via email (for free obviously), give your business card. When emailing back, you can add your business signature. Word of mouth works good, as good as, watermarked photos on stranger's facebook timelines.

Apart from business, it would be great opportunity for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Marketing is all about putting your message out where your target audience will see it. Do they use Instagram? Make sure you have one. Do they use Facebook? Get that one too. You can duplicate posts between platforms but do keep in mind that people use platforms for different things. Images *with great stories* work better on Facebook than images alone.

Try your hand at digital advertising. Facebook will let you refine a target audience based on demographics that you get to select and then you can cap a max budget for the campaign.

The absolute cheapest way to get new clients is in repeat business and referrals. What are you doing currently to encourage repeat business? What are you doing to encourage referrals? Do you find reasons to reach back out to clients? (For example, let's say you photographed an Engagement Session. When was the wedding? Did you send a card? Were they planning on kids? Is it in your calendar to check in with them about family portraits?)

With high school seniors in particular, photographing someone in a clique is a great way to get the rest of the gang knocking at your door. Make sure they have a good time during the shoot, love their images, and make sure they have a shareable version ASAP (something they can post on social media bragging).

Answer (score 0):

Your potential customers are people fond of selfies, right? So "hunting" them in social medias seems a good idea. Try instagram or FB. you can also offer discounts for those who participate in 3 photoshots. Browse your colleagues profiles to search for clients too. Enter local communities.